# How can I test this module using Nancy.testing

Tags: .net, nancy

I'm struggling with this...
Well, I have a .Net Core Console Application project using Nancy, this is what I got

```
using Nancy;

    public class HomeModule : NancyModule
    {
        public HomeModule()
        {
            Get("/", args => HttpStatusCode.OK);

            Post("/", args => HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
    }
```

And I was trying to test this

```
public void simplest_get_test()
{
      var browser = new Browser(with => with.Module(new HomeModule()));

      var response = browser.Get("/", with => {
          with.HttpRequest();
      });

}
```

I want to do something like this, and I don't know if the browser instance is right

```
Assert.AreEqual(HttpStatusCode.OK, response);
```

But I don't how, I'm a little bit lost

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks about right. What problems are you having?

Answer (score 0):

Since your response is an instance of [HttpWebResponse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httpwebresponse?view=netframework-4.7.2), you need to change your assertion to:

```
Assert.AreEqual(HttpStatusCode.OK, response.StatusCode);
```

Other than that it looks fine.